# Correct way to figure out what rejection a promise had?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I have an API / express router:

```
router.post("/signup", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        var user = await controllers.user.register(req.body.username, req.body.password);
        req.session.user = user;
        res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json("DB Error");
    }
});
```

Currently, on error, it returns 500 DB error. This is my controller:

```
function register(username, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ username: username }).lean().exec((e, doc) => {
            if (e) reject(e);
            if (doc) {
                reject("Username already exists.");
            } else {
                var user = new User({ username, password: hash(password) });
                user.save((e) => {
                    if (e) reject(e);
                    else {
                        delete user.password;
                        resolve(user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

What's the right way to return a 400 if username already exists, and a 500 if it was a database error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose already uses promises, the use of `new Promise` is promise construction antipattern.

Express doesn't have the concept of controllers, there are only route handlers and middlewares. Since `register` should be very aware of the way it will be used in a response, there may be no need for another level of abstraction above route handler. There will be no problem when a function has access to handler parameters and can form a response in-place.

It can be:

```
router.post("/signup", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const { body, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: username }).lean();
        if (user) {
          res.status(400).json("Username already exists");
        } else {
          ...
          res.json(user);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json("DB Error");
    }
});
```

In case route handler needs to be reused in multiple places with some variations, it could be refactored to higher-order function or some other helper that is aware of original `req` and `res` parameters.

Comment: Can you show what the higher-order function looks like? By helper / higher-order function, I'm thinking basically my controller that takes `username` and `password` as parameters and returns a promise that the router waits for to handle accordingly.

Comment: I'm asking because I have controllers used with more than one API. Example: A `/create/post` API taking `user` and `content` as `req`, that calls a `Post.controller.create(user, content)` controller. The controller calls `User.controller.get(user)` to get the user object, then creates a `Post` object using the `user` objects `ID` and the `content` as `content`. `User.controller.get` is the controller used in multiple places.

Comment: Higher-order handler can be `createHandler = isPasswordHashed => async (req, res) => { /* same as above, with conditionally hashed password */`.You use it like `router.post("/signup", createHandler(true))`. Do you reuse the function with variations? If you don't, you don't need higher-order handlers. You can have single handler function and use it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way you are rejecting the Promise. I'd suggest something like:

```
function register(username, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ username: username }).lean().exec((e, doc) => {
            if (e) reject(500);
            if (doc) {
                reject(400);
            } else {
                var user = new User({ username, password: hash(password) });
                user.save((e) => {
                    if (e) reject(500);
                    else {
                        delete user.password;
                        resolve(user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

And in the route:

```
router.post("/signup", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        var user = await controllers.user.register(req.body.username, req.body.password);
        req.session.user = user;
        res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(e).json(e == 400 ? "Username already exists." : "DB Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. It'd be best for me to go through my app and make sure all rejects are like this to stay consistent. Is this a better approach then making my register function like this `if (doc) { var user = null } else { user = new User() }` and then in the `router.post`: `try { var user = await; if user == null { res.status(400) } else { req.session.user = user; res.json(user) }` ?

Comment: To be honest I don't like to handle the reference object to indicate the error. I prefer this one or return a structured object, like: `reject({ code: 400, msg: 'User already exists'});` and chanding the code and message in each scenario. What do you think?

Comment: Your `reject({ code: 400, msg: 'User already exists'});` method looks good. Can you provide a link to the `Promise` documentation that shows the parameters `reject` can take? I didn't know we can pass that type of array.